# JSF2.0 Primefaces p:selectCheckboxMenu

Tags: jsf, primefaces, glassfish

Running on my MacBook

> - JSF2.0
> - Primefaces 3.4.2
> - Eclipse Juno
> - Glassfish

When I run this code;

```
<h:form>
<h:outputText value="SMSC:" />

<p:selectCheckboxMenu id="graphsmscnames"
value="#{reportBean.selectedSmsclist}" label="SMSC" filter="true"
filterText="Filter" filterMatchMode="startsWith"
panelStyle="width:250px">

<f:selectItems value="#{reportBean.smsclist}" />

</p:selectCheckboxMenu>

<p:message for="graphsmscnames" />

<p:commandButton id="graphgenreport" value="Generate"
update=":reportpanel" action="#{reportBean.test}" />

</h:form>
```

and code in managedBean (with getters/setters for smsclist variable and selectedSmscList)

```
Map<String, String> smsclist;
private List<String> selectedSmsclist;

public constructure(){
smsclist=new HashMap<String,String>();
smsclist.put("one","one");
smsclist.put("two","two");
}

public void test(){
System.out.println(selectedSmsclist.size());
    }
```

Even when multiple/single items are selected from UI - it doesnt reflect inside my managedBean when commandButton is pressed. selectedSmscList List size is still zero.

Comment: What is the scope of your managed bean? The wrong scope will guarantee that your `selectedSmcList` will always be initialized to empty. Use `@ViewScoped` to be safe. Hint: it's unnecessary to override the constructor of your managed bean, use a `@PostConstruct` annotation on a method that will do the same job instead.

Comment: Its ViewScoped - really appreciate PostConstruct suggestion. It turns out that if I used multiple p:selectCheckboxMenu inside a single form, only  one works and the other doesnt. So I worked out the UI to live with this for now because of time constraint. Appreciate your help.